# Automatic capacitor discharge circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, solar-cell, discharge

I need a (preferably analog) circuit to monitor a solar cell trickle-charged capacitor and automatically discharge the capacitor when it's charged. The idea is to use solar cells to power small solenoids or motors for remote outdoor devices, intermittent and random discharges are fine. I plan on trying several sizes of solar cells and capacitors to see what works best in various applications. If you know of a good reference, I should look at, that would be great.

Comment: Are you planning for your monitoring circuit to draw power from the storage capacitor? If no, from where? And if yes, what's the approximate voltage range on the storage cap?

Comment: Is this for some kind of science field experiment with mobile, self-powered devices that can move around in fits and starts? Mostly just curious. What you are looking for, though, in very general terms is to add a voltage trigger followed by an SCR.

Comment: Jonk, that's pretty much the idea. I need some platforms to move somewhat randomly.

Comment: FrontRanger, yes I was hoping to use the solar cell to power the monitoring circuit. I can add a battery as well.

Comment: Jonk, Wow! thank you so much. I have asked many EEs this question and nobody ever even mentioned that a thing called a voltage trigger existed.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but all of them need more details.  What is the open-circuit (no-load) solar cell voltage?  What is the peak current during discharge?  What are the minimum and maximum desired discharge times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I dont know the details, here can be a possible aproach. The whole idea is to generate a constant width pulse for discharging cap thru mosfet (and cap protecting resistance) once the voltage reaches desired level (about 10v in this case). This pulse is generated with monostable circuit fired by voltage monitor made with zener. The components needs to be designed according timings , i.e. cap size, discharge rate etc.. For higher accuracy use 555 timer as monostable and TL431 as voltage monitor.

In waveforms the green is cap voltage, blue is discharging pulse.

[image]

[image: green is cap voltage, blue discharging pulse]

To avoid "shorting" solar cell thru 1 ohm resistance when discharging, the panel can be disconnected for this short of time adding P-chan mosfet right after cell.

[image]